# Unknown users of app on internal test track in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, beta-testing, google-play-internal-testing

I just published a test version of my app on the Internal Test Track in Google Play Console. I'm the only tester selected in the list.

My app sends some logging to my server, and there I can see that there have been about 20 different installs of my app just minutes after I released it on the internal test track!

Who are these users??

They seem to use different hardware, but many of them report their `host` as 
`vpeb11.mtv.corp.google.com` and similar, but I'm also seeing some ranom ones like `bjfih025`.

Is this Google testing my app? I thought an **internal** test track was only visible to the people I have added as testers, not random Google employees or Google bots?

Comment: I have also seen the same thing myself, it shows up in my Firebase console too. Confused me to start with. I also put it down too Googles auto testing.

Answer (score 6):

This is likely to be installs from the **pre-launch report**: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en-GB

To turn off pre-launch report, you can follow the instructions at that link (copied here for convenience):

> ### Turn off all pre-launch reports
>
> Pre-launch reports are automatically generated when you publish an app to the open, closed or internal test track. To disable all pre-launch reports for your app:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. Select **Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings**.
> 4. Next to 'Enable pre-launch reports', move the switch to the left until it turns grey. If you want to turn pre-launch reports on again at a later time, move the switch back to the right until it turns blue.